# gnuplot png unkown and pdf error

Tags: gnuplot, ubuntu-10.04

I have a shell script that performs some calculations and plot the results. I have used gnuplot for plotting the results. I'm facing two problems. I used to run the script on my cygwin and it's Okay. When I tried to run it on Ubuntu (Version 10.04-wubi-version), it couldn't recognize the png files (set terminal png unknown). I have tried to install (missing libraries that support "libgd2_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg" and update the libraries.... no luck !! then I have decided to use set terminal pdf instead since I found it supported :

here is my gnuplot version:

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.4 patchlevel 0
last modified March 2010
System: Linux 2.6.35-32-generic
```

here is the output of terminal types:

```
      latex  LaTeX picture environment
      mf  Metafont plotting standard
      mif  Frame maker MIF 3.00 format
      mp  MetaPost plotting standard
      nec_cp6  NEC printer CP6, Epson LQ-800 [monocrome color draft]
      okidata  OKIDATA 320/321 Standard
      pbm  Portable bitmap [small medium large] [monochrome gray color]
      pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
      -->pdf  PDF (Portable Document File) file driver
      postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
      pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
      pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
```

Now, After I have modified the shell script to use pdf, I'm getting this error (Note: some of the pdf files are created ).

```
line 0: ';' expected
```

Again, I've added ';' to all of the lines.... and the error still appears.

Here is part of my shell script (that gives the error):

```
  gnuplot << TOEND ;
  set terminal pdf;
  set output 'A.pdf';
  set autoscale ;                        
  #unset log                              
  #unset label                            
  set xtic auto ;                         
  set ytic auto  ;                        
  set title "title";
  set xlabel "x axis";
  set ylabel "y axis";
   ######################################
   #UPDATE: I have added double space to a void the error  
   ######################################
   plot "A1.tr" using 1:2 title "A" with lines 9,  \  
    "A2.tr" using 1:2 title "B" with lines 11
```

the output (Note this part is not of the created pdf files):

```
line 0: invalid character \ --->pointing to 9, \
line 0: invalid command --->poiting to A2.tr
```

the rest of shell script produces the same error (Note: output is created)

```
......
......
######################################
#UPDATE:  @psibar pointed that 'ls' missing    
######################################
plot "results.tr" using 1:2 title "Results" with lines ls 9;
                                                                           ^
line 0: ';' expected---> pointing to 9 ;
```

After long searching, I think the problem has to do with version of UBUNTU and Gnuplot....I don't want to upgrade my version of ubuntu.....

After solving the errors. Any suggestions on how to get the "set terminal png" works on ubuntu 10.04 ??

Comment: What are the numbers 9 and 11 doing there at the end of the `plot` commands? I think there is something missing. Shouldn't it be rather `… with lines ls 9` ?

Comment: 9 is for the line style... your are right I was missing 'ls'... But still getting : line 0: invalid character \ --->pointing after 9, \
line 0: invalid command --->poiting to A2.tr

Comment: I solved the problem. I put double space after the ',  \' to overcome the error. Check the update....

Comment: Yes this is a very annoying error, which served me some headaches as well.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy : you can answer your own question to provide information for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I have added `ls` and double spaces after the `9, \`.

The final answer would be :

```
gnuplot << TOEND ;
set terminal pdf;
set output 'A.pdf';
set autoscale ;                        
#unset log                              
#unset label                            
set xtic auto ;                         
set ytic auto  ;                        
set title "title";
set xlabel "x axis";
set ylabel "y axis";
######################################
#UPDATE: I have added double space to a void the error 
# and @psibar pointed that 'ls' was missing
######################################
plot "A1.tr" using 1:2 title "A" with lines ls 9,  \  
"A2.tr" using 1:2 title "B" with lines 11
```